# Set up a summation notation from a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, recursion, arithmetic-progressions

I want to set up a summation notation for numbers of blocks that is needed in a podium with n layers but I dont know how to do that.

I calculated the following sequence:
first layer: 9 blocks
second layer: 16 block
third layer: 25 blocks
forth layer: 36 blocks

From first layer to second layer 7 more blocks is added, second layer to third layer 9 more blocks is added, third layer to forth layer 11 blocks is added and so on.

I also came up with the recursive formula: 
a(n) = a(n-1) + (a(n-1) - a(n-2)) + 2 (but I dont know if that will help me)

Comment: Looks like $(n+2)^2$ to me.

Answer (score 1):

Consecutive odd numbers do add up to perfect squares so for a strict sum you could try:

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n+2} (2k-1)$

The thing in brackets ensures the first layer has nine blocks. It's like I shifted the actual thing to remain between 0 and n

Comment: So the first layer, k = 1 should be 9. But 2(1+2) - 1 = 5. Do I think correct or?

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks for the correction. There's something I mixed up

Comment: No problems! Can you explain your edited version a bit more? I have to start with k=5 to get the first layer to be 9.

Comment: Don't think of it in reverse. I was asked for a summation and produced it. In that case what you would get isn't just 5 but the sum of every odd number up to 5. It's a summation basically.

Comment: And besides, that knowledge actually stems from that very fact. For proving that, I unfortunately do not have any quick internet sources. But if you pose the question I'll do my best to answer it.